# Elif statement to check for sheet range

Tags: python

I have several Excel files some with 10 worksheets others with 8. In my code I looping through all files and selecting a sheet range of 2 to 9. However, since I have some workbooks with 8 sheets I would like to do the same loop or action in these workbooks instead of getting the "sheets = wb.worksheets[n]
IndexError: list index out of range". Can I use elif to accomplish this?

```
import glob
import openpyxl

path = 'C:/ExcelFolder/*.xlsx'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
  Sheet = wb.worksheets
  if Sheet is range(2, 9):
    for n in range(2, 9):
        sheets = wb.worksheets[n]
        #Do something
  elif Sheet is range(2, 5):
    for n in range(2, 5):
        sheets = wb.worksheets[n]
        #Do something
```

Comment: `try: foo() ; except: pass` dirty but you can try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if...elif` isn't entirely necessary.

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to *slice* your `Sheets`:

```
from itertools import islice

for file in files:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    Sheets = wb.worksheets
    for sheet in islice(Sheets, 2, 9):
        # do something with sheet
```

If `Sheets` isn't up to length `9`, the iteration stops at the length of `Sheets`, say `5`.